# Passing call status variable from Split based on widget

Tags: twilio-studio

I have a flow in which I'm connecting a salesperson to a client, so now I need to branch out to the next step depending on the status of this call.
From the documentation, I have to use the variable `{{widgets.MYWIDGET.DialCallStatus}}` the values possible are:

- queued
- initiated
- ringing
- in-progress
- completed
- busy
- failed
- no-answer
  I have attached a screenshot with the configuration. Thanks in advance.

[image: Studio Flow]

I'm testing some values but is resulting in `NO MATCH`?
I can see in the logs that is entering to the Split based on widget but the variable status is not being recognized?

Answer (score 0):

I did not test this, but the [documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/connect-call#connect-call-to-variables) shows that the Connect Call To widget returns data in this format:

```
Dial Call Status {{widgets.MY_WIDGET_NAME.variables.DialCallStatus}}
```

Is the "variables" property shown when you inspect it in the debug log?

If so, try this selector: {{widgets.Forward_call_to_contact.variables.DialCallStatus}}

Comment: HI! I tried that with no luck. The debug log  doesn't show any variables property. I don't think the Connect Call to is storing the DialCallStatus (child call) as the documentation says, but the CallStatus (parent). Since I'm making a connection from the sales to the client, after the API called the sales, it is the child call status what I need.

Comment: You can use the Set Variables Widget to save variables that can be accessed from any other subsequent widget. Would that be an option? In the picture I don't see a parent or a child call (or don't understand how they are labelled). Also, is your Studio Flow returning status callbacks to itself? This is the default but you might have overridden the "call status change" endpoint to your own endpoint. This could explain why the status callbacks are being sent according to the debug log but have a null/empty value when trying to access.

Comment: The problem is that this variable should be generated once the Connect call to widget is executed. I'm using set variables widget at the beggining of the flow to pass values that I bring to the flow. The link os here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/connect-call#connect-call-to-variables

Comment: For troubleshooting, try the Set Variable Widget later in the flow after you know you should have the value. You might use multiple Set Variable Widgets and then use the Liquid Templating Language. For example, set a variable early in the flow. Set another variable later in the flow. Use Liquid to determine which variable to use in subsequent Widgets. For what it is worth, at some point, Twilio Functions or some other external function (like Azure Functions) will be necessary to maintain state and perform complex logic. https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/user-guide/liquid-template-language